# Eclipse RCP build - missing javax.xml

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am updating my RCP target from circa 2015 to latest.

I have a requirement for Java XML Streaming that I resolve from the p2 site Orbit-R20200529191137 - https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200529191137/repository.  This feature has a requirement for javax.xml.

When building I get a new error that did not occur with the old target file:

```
Missing requirement: mybundle.core.support.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'javax.xml 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Any suggestions on how I can meet this requirement.

Thanks for the time to read and think about my question,
Timothy

From a post on Eclipse forums this VERY useful link to a release specific migration guide.

[Migration guide](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fporting%2Fremovals.html&anchor=updatemanager)

**Adding target platform**

The target platform is defined using software sites only so that it is compatible with Tycho build.  Here is the text view of the ***OLD*** target file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="motordb-4" sequenceNumber="179">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.M1" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/gemini/jpa/updates" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.collections.source" version="3.2.0.v2013030210310" />
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.collections" version="3.2.0.v2013030210310" />
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.beanutils" version="1.8.0.v201205091237" />
            <unit id="javax.xml.stream" version="1.0.1.v201004272200" />
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.net" version="3.2.0.v201305141515" />
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.net.source" version="3.2.0.v201305141515" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group" version="2.11.0.v20150805-0538" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.feature.group" version="2.11.1.v20150805-0538" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.5.1.v20150904-0015" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.11.1.v20150831-1342" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.help.source.feature.group" version="2.1.1.v20150904-0015" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.101.v20150826-1318" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.5.1.v20150904-0015" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.help.feature.group" version="2.1.1.v20150904-0015" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.feature.group" version="2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.source.feature.group" version="2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/updates/" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.hamcrest" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.text" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.integration" version="1.3.0.v201305210900" />
            <unit id="org.junit" version="4.11.0.v201303080030" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.generator" version="1.3.0.v201305210900" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="1.3.0.v201303031735" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.library" version="1.3.0.v201305281000" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.core.source" version="1.3.0.v201303031735" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.generator.source" version="1.3.0.v201305210900" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.library.source" version="1.3.0.v201305281000" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.text" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000" />
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.integration.source" version="1.3.0.v201305210900" />
            <unit id="org.junit.source" version="4.11.0.v201303080030" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.2.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.feature.group" version="1.3.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.2.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.rosgi.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.source.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.2.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.sdk.source.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.2.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.source.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.rosgi.source.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.source.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.source.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.2.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.source.feature.feature.group" version="1.3.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.source.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.2.v20160823-2221" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.source.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.v20160823-2221" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/3.13.2/site.p2" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="ch.qos.logback.core" version="1.0.7.v20121108-1250" />
            <unit id="org.slf4j.log4j" version="1.7.2.v20130115-1340" />
            <unit id="org.slf4j.ext" version="1.7.2.v20121108-1250" />
            <unit id="org.slf4j.jcl" version="1.7.2.v20130115-1340" />
            <unit id="ch.qos.logback.slf4j" version="1.0.7.v20121108-1250" />
            <unit id="org.slf4j.jul" version="1.7.2.v20121108-1250" />
            <unit id="ch.qos.logback.classic" version="1.0.7.v20121108-1250" />
            <unit id="org.slf4j.api" version="1.7.2.v20121108-1250" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.RELEASE" />
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/gemini/updates/dbaccess/1.1.0" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="com.custom.support.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.5.201811071810" />
            <unit id="com.custom.ecf.websockets.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.201512220910" />
            <unit id="com.apache.pdfbox.feature.group" version="1.0.0.201505111049" />
            <repository location="http://localhost/development/" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190602212107/repository" />
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.math3" version="3.5.0.v20160301-1110" />
        </location>
    </locations>
    <targetJRE path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8" />
</target>
```

and the ***updated NEW*** one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="motordb-5" sequenceNumber="183">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.M1"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/gemini/jpa/updates"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="1.3.0.v201303031735"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.core.source" version="1.3.0.v201303031735"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.generator" version="1.3.0.v201305210900"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.generator.source" version="1.3.0.v201305210900"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.integration" version="1.3.0.v201305210900"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.integration.source" version="1.3.0.v201305210900"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.library" version="1.3.0.v201305281000"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.library.source" version="1.3.0.v201305281000"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.text" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000"/>
    <unit id="org.hamcrest.text" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000"/>
    <unit id="org.junit" version="4.11.0.v201303080030"/>
    <unit id="org.junit.source" version="4.11.0.v201303080030"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.feature.group" version="2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.source.feature.group" version="2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/updates/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.RELEASE"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/gemini/updates/dbaccess/1.1.0"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="com.easa.motodb.support.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.5.201811071810"/>
<unit id="com.vogelware.ecf.websockets.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.201512220910"/>
<unit id="com.apache.pdfbox.feature.group" version="1.0.0.201505111049"/>
<repository location="http://vogelware.com/development/"/>
</location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/3.14.7/site.p2"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.feature.group" version="1.5.500.v20200217-1548"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.5.500.v20200217-1548"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.300.v20191023-2007"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.1.300.v20191023-2007"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.feature.feature.group" version="3.14.700.v20200217-0016"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.feature.source.feature.group" version="3.14.700.v20200217-0016"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.feature.feature.group" version="3.14.7.v20200114-1512"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.feature.source.feature.group" version="3.14.7.v20200114-1512"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.200.v20191024-1546"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.1.200.v20191024-1546"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.200.v20191024-1546"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.1.200.v20191024-1546"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.feature.feature.group" version="2.5.102.v20191031-1454"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.5.102.v20191031-1454"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.rosgi.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.2.v20200217-0038"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.rosgi.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.1.2.v20200217-0038"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="3.14.7.v20200217-0120"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.sdk.feature.source.feature.group" version="3.14.7.v20200217-0120"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient45.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.300.v20200217-0016"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient45.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.0.300.v20200217-0016"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.16"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group" version="2.19.0.v20200324-0932"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.feature.group" version="2.22.0.v20200519-1135"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group" version="1.4.800.v20200602-1138"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.20.200.v20200528-0603"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.help.feature.group" version="2.3.200.v20200604-0540"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.help.source.feature.group" version="2.3.200.v20200604-0540"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.16.0.v20200604-0951"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.16.0.v20200604-0951"/>
    </location> 
    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200529191137/repository"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.classic" version="1.0.7.v20121108-1250"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.classic" version="1.2.3.v20200428-2012"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.core" version="1.0.7.v20121108-1250"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.core" version="1.2.3.v20200428-2012"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.slf4j" version="1.2.3.v20200428-2012"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.api" version="1.7.2.v20121108-1250"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.api" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.apis.jcl" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.apis.log4j" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.bridge.jul" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.ext" version="1.7.2.v20121108-1250"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.ext" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.jcl" version="1.7.2.v20130115-1340"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.jul" version="1.7.2.v20121108-1250"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.log4j" version="1.7.2.v20130115-1340"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200529191137/repository"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.beanutils" version="1.8.0.v201205091237"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.collections" version="3.2.2.v201511171945"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.net" version="3.2.0.v201305141515"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.math3" version="3.5.0.v20190611-1023"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06"/>
        <unit id="javax.xml.bind" version="0.0.0"/>
    </location> 
</locations>
<targetJRE path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
</target>
```

Error when running RCP with new target file
[image: Error image]

Target Platform State with updated new target file
[image: Target Platform State]

Excerpt from javax.xml.stream Manifest

```
Require-Bundle: javax.xml, system.bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.1.v201004272200
Export-Package: javax.xml;version="1.0.1"
```

javax.xml.* in bundle cache directory
[image: javax.xml.* bundles]

Comment: It seems the `javax.xml` plugin/bundle is missing in your new target platform (`0.0.0` means of any version). In which way (there are several) did you define the target platform? Show what you have.

Comment: That looks like the old target platform. For example, `https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5` is from 2015  (`https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.16` is the latest). In a `<locaction>` with such a specific `<repository>` all verions in `<unit>` elements should be `0.0.0`. Otherwise, when updating you also have to adapt the version of each unit.

Comment: Well that was somewhat embarrassing ... I added the correct one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following snippet to your new target definition file should fix this issue (and make `<unit id="javax.xml.stream" version="1.0.1.v201004272200"/>` obsolete):

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
    <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06"/>
    <unit id="javax.xml" version="0.0.0"/>
</location>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error after making the suggested changes.  I updated the original post with screen shots that show the manifest requiring the javax.xml bundle and that it is missing from the target definition.
Any other ideas / suggestions?

Comment: I went back to the 2015 version and confirmed javax.xml bundle was included.  I then started removing items from the target file until it was no longer listed on the content page.  The bundle was added by <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.5.1.v20150904-0015"/>.  I'm not sure where to go from here ... a bug report with RCP team?

Comment: @TimothyVogel Sorry, `<unit id="javax.xml" version="0.0.0"/>`, not `<unit id="javax.xml.bind" version="0.0.0"/>` (see my updated answer). `org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group` does not require it anymore, but you still require it. So it's up to you to add it. For locations with a repository location containing a version number, the unit version should be `version="0.0.0"` (otherwise, it's hard to maintain since you cannot just switch the repository location).

Comment: That worked!  Can you share the technique you used to find the repository that provides that bundle?

Comment: I just checked whether it is part of my Java Eclipse IDE. And since it is, it must either be in `https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.16` (Eclipse platform + JDT) or/and in `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06` (simultaneous release repository containing everything and more from which the various IDE packages of a release are made). Use the repository of a simultaneous release as much as possible, since this is what was tested in this combination of versions and it also makes it super easy to upgrade (assuming you have `<unit ... version="0.0.0"/>`).